# APNS - Taking App Out of Production and into Development

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, parse-platform

I've got an iOS app using push notifications via Parse.com, and I'd like to do some testing where notifications are only sent to test devices. If I simply switch over to a development certificate, I presume the notifications won't go to production devices.

However, I'm slightly concerned about doing something wrong and accidentally trying to send hundreds of thousands of push notifications to production devices via the development certificate.

I know the production devices would not receive the notifications, but would there be any wider issue to something like this happening - i.e. my app getting flagged as spam or something like that?

Comment: Just like Eran mentioned, the production token is different from the development token. So, if you send the message to Apple Sandbox server, it will not reach the devices with the production token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try to send notifications to production device tokens using development certificate (and connecting to APNS sandbox server), you'll get an error of invalid device token for each notification and the connection will be closed after each message you send. Most of the messages won't even reach Apple, since they close the connection once they find an invalid message, and all the messages sent after that message are discarded.

A bigger problem would be if you store sandbox (=development) device tokens in the same DB as the production tokens. If you don't distinguish between the two types of tokens, when you switch back to production push notifications, you run the risk of trying to send notifications to sandbox tokens using the production push certificate, which would give you errors and close your connection to APNS, thus disrupting the push to the production tokens. Therefore I strongly suggest that you use a different DB to store the sandbox device tokens.

Comment: Agree. It is best to distinguish between production server and testing (development) server.

Comment: I'm using Parse.com, not implementing the db myself. So, if I did send out notifications to production tokens using a dev cert, those notifications would just be ignored? I just want to be able to send out notifications to development devices while I'm testing, but since I'm using Parse.com and haven't implemented the db I don't think I have much control over which tokens the notifications are sent to. So, I thought, if I just switch over to a dev cert, production tokens will be ignored and development ones will be delivered to development devices. Is this a bad idea?

Comment: @user1718136 I don't know how Parse implement the DB (When you send the device token to them, do you have a way to specify if you are sending a production token or a sandbox token?). I'm just saying that having both development and production tokens in the same DB will cause you problems when pushing to production (since sandbox tokens may cause the connection to close all the time).

Comment: @user1718136 Sending notifications to production tokens using a dev cert will cause the connection to APNS to be closed due to invalid device token. Don't you have a way to request from Parse to push to specific device tokens?